# Is DataGridView wrong choice?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, dataset

I am new to C# and Windows Forms so please be patient. I am making a Windows Form that lets you load a video, load a script, then makes captions. I want to display a table where the data will be populated automatically as they mark starts and ends of caption and select text and will be editable. At the end I want to save all the data to an xml file. A DataGridView UI-wise seems like exactly what I want, but I can't figure out backend how to get the data out of the DataGridView ( preferably in a dataset).

I am now considering using a `ListView` with multiple columns instead. Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: DataGridView is probably easier to use, as to the fact that it is directly "convertable" to a DataSet :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Datagridview should work just fine for that application and you can easily retrieve any data you save to it by doing:

```
    dgvThing.DataSource;
```

That will contain whatever type that you have saved into the Datagridview (List, array, etc).

Example:

```
    public class SuperFunObject {
        public TimeSpan start { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan end { get; set; }
        public string selectedText { get; set; }
        public SuperFunObject(Timespan a, Timespan b, string text) {
            start = a;
            end = b;
            selectedText = text;
        }
    }
    List<SuperFunObject> funList = new List<SuperFunObject>();
    funList.Add(new SuperFunObject(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.0),TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20.0),"Hello"));
    dgvThing.DataSource = funList;
    ...
    ...
    //retrive your list
    List<SuperFunObject> getData = ((List<SuperFunObject>)dgvThing.DataSource);
```

I hope the example helps a bit. Side note, the reason for the accessors (get,set) are for the Datagridview to be able to retrieve the data from the object for display.

Comment: @AlexInTime - he beat you to saying what you were going to say and you didn't even upvote.  Sadness.

Comment: This is what I originally tried, but it just returns null

Comment: @BrianMikeyHalbert: Can you show the code that you used to retrieve the data and the code that you use to assign it to the gridview?

Comment: @BrianMikeyHalbert Does the example help a bit?

Comment: @Andrew_CS I totally forgot

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little ditty that'll save a class that you populate into an array from your datasource to am XML file path that you specify in the parameter.

```
public static bool SaveXMLObjectToFile(object IncomingXMLObject, string Path)   
{

string xmlString = null;
File TheFileIn = default(File);
string docname = null;
StreamWriter WriteAFile = default(StreamWriter);
string filelocation = null;
//Dim filelocation As String

System.IO.MemoryStream MemStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer Ser = default(System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer);
System.Text.Encoding encodingvalue = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
System.Xml.XmlTextWriter writer = new System.Xml.XmlTextWriter(MemStream, encodingvalue);

bool Result = false;

try {
    File.Delete(Path);
    Ser = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(IncomingXMLObject.GetType);
    Ser.Serialize(writer, IncomingXMLObject);
    MemStream = writer.BaseStream;
    //as system.io.memorystream
    xmlString = UTF8ByteArrayToString(MemStream.ToArray());
    //Will Not Convert Byte Array from Diagram
    filelocation = Path;
    WriteAFile = TheFileIn.AppendText(filelocation);
    WriteAFile.Write(xmlString);
    WriteAFile.Close();
    Result = true;
} catch (Exception e) {
    Result = false;
}

return Result;

}
```